Do bitcoin or crypto assets impact the total supply of money in a country?
Bitcoin like crypto asset are invisible coins or on boarding coins that have the implicit value and intrinsic values but accepted as legal tender currencies in India by RBI.

I think this would be a better question on economics.SE.  It is interesting, does gold mining increase the money supply?  That works as a functional means to transfer value in the US.

It does not mean how much we have gold mines as bullion.I am asking about gold bullion market.Instead it,I want to explain about the exchange value of gold in our Reserve bank of India.That the gold reserve held by the central bank against the printing of legal tender currency.Gold mining and mint cost are both different  in meaning.Gold standard is although invalid in our monetary system but the prevalence of freely floating exchange rate and purchasing power parity theory has been adopted in present day monetary system.Gold reserve act as a differed payment in exchange market as well as PPT.


Do bitcoin or crypto assets impact the total supply of money in a country?

They must do in practical terms, just as the use of foreign currency does
However, though not an economist, I suspect economists most often report on the money supply of a single government-mandated currency. This would be a question for an economics stack exchange website if one exists.


accepted as legal tender currencies in India by RBI.

Not so far as I can see
https://www.rbi.org.in/commonman/English/Scripts/PressReleases.aspx?Id=2152

The Reserve Bank of India advises that it has not given any licence / authorisation to any entity / company to operate such schemes or deal with Bitcoin or any virtual currency. As such, any user, holder, investor, trader, etc. dealing with Virtual Currencies will be doing so at their own risk.

Legal tender
The phrase "legal tender" has a special meaning, at least in jurisdictions following the UK model - it determines what forms of payment can be legally used in settlement of a debt. A shopkeeper can refuse legal tender offered for payment for goods or services  where there is no established debt.

The bit coin is a virtual currency ofcourse.As,l am not confirmed about latest RBI information.Although,it is not accepted as legal tender currency but it is considered as legal in circulation among the stake holders.So,I am sorry about this wrong information.However,the bitcoin never contribute in total supply of money of a country.Because total supply of money in our country consists of M1, M2,M3 and M4 but this bitcoin is not included among theses four category of money.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
